# I want to automate invalid and valid credentials

Tags: java, selenium

I am doing [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) automation with page factory design pattern for a web application. Now I want to do automate valid valid, invalid invalid, valid invalid credential for a login page. How is it?

My complete code is

```
package com.docmgr.Pages;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.CacheLookup;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    public class LoginPage
    {
        WebDriver driver;
        public LoginPage(WebDriver driver)
        {
            this.driver=driver;
        }
        @FindBy(how=How.NAME,using="username")
        @CacheLookup
        WebElement username;
        @FindBy(how=How.NAME,using="password")
        @CacheLookup
        WebElement password;
        @FindBy(how=How.CLASS_NAME,using="button")
        @CacheLookup
        WebElement button;
        @FindBy(how=How.LINK_TEXT,using="Forgot Password")
        @CacheLookup
        WebElement fp;
        public void login_Doc(String uid,String pas)
        {
            username.sendKeys(uid);
            password.sendKeys(pas);
            button.click();
        }
    }


    package com.docmgr.TestCases;

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    import com.docmgr.Pages.LoginPage;

    import Helper.BrowserFactory;

    public class LoginTest
    {
        @Test
        public void chechValidUser()
        {
            System.setProperty("firefox.webdriver.marionette","pathToGeckodriver");
            WebDriver driver=BrowserFactory.startBrowser("firefox","54.68.159.876/docmgr");
            LoginPage login=PageFactory.initElements(driver,LoginPage.class);
            login.login_Doc("jgsdg","123");
        }
    }

    package Helper;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    public class BrowserFactory
    {
        static WebDriver driver;
        public static WebDriver startBrowser(String browsName,String url)
        {
            if(browsName.equals("firefox"))
            {
                driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            }

            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(url);
            return driver;
        }
    }
```

Comment: add valid and invalid credentials in excel sheet and by getting them you can able to perform automation

Comment: @PotnuruRavi  My question is in my login test page, how to write coding for valid, invalid credential. here I put valid detail.

Comment: By giving input credentials only we can say that the given credentials are valid or invalid. So for that, we need to maintain test data in excel or database. we need to get the same from the repository either from db or excel and have to perform automation by calling each test data means valid and invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass an extra parameter for `login_Doc` method which denotes that the give user name and password is valid or not. Look at below example.

```
public void login_Doc(String uid,String pas,boolean isValidCredential)
{
    username.sendKeys(uid);
    password.sendKeys(pas);
    button.click();
    if(isValidCredential == true){
      // check if user is logged in successfully and click on logout button
   } else {
      //check appropriate error message is displayed
    }
}
```

and call the `login.login_Doc` method as,

```
  login.login_Doc("admin","admin",true); //valid credential
  login.login_Doc("admin","admin123",false); //invalid credential
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tests will look like this:

```
public class LoginTest
{
@Test
public void chechValidUser()
{
    login.login_Doc("valid","valid");
}

@Test
public void chechValidInvalidUser()
{
    login.login_Doc("valid","invalid");
    String bodyText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
    Assert.assertTrue("Text not found!", bodyText.contains("Invalid Password"));
}

@Test
public void chechInvalidInvalidUser()
{
    login.login_Doc("invalid","invalid");
    String bodyText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
    Assert.assertTrue("Text not found!", bodyText.contains("Invalid Username"));
}
}
```

If you change your login function to this:

```
public void login_Doc(String uid,String pas)
{
    System.setProperty("firefox.webdriver.marionette","pathToGeckodriver");
    WebDriver driver=BrowserFactory.startBrowser("firefox","54.68.159.876/docmgr");
    LoginPage login=PageFactory.initElements(driver,LoginPage.class);
    username.sendKeys(uid);
    password.sendKeys(pas);
    button.click();
 }
```

Comment: Is there any easy way ?

Comment: Easy? you mean validating if it  is invalid? or your tests should more compact and readable?

Comment: See to make it looks simple, you need to modularize it further! Your tests should look like "Login(user,password),  Get text() and assert statement to validate.

Comment: regarding validating the error message, this is the very basic way to check the error message on the web page.

Comment: ya understood. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127865/discussion-between-antony-naveen-and-waman).